# unable to find specified column in result set index out of bounds index out of range exception

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am having trouble putting a value in a textbox. Each time a ticket is sold i put the total price in a textbox, each time a ticket is sold for the same concert it increases by adding its self to the total price. It works at the first sale, but after that it breaks down. here is the code and thanks in advance.

```
 Private Function DisplayMoneyTaken() As Integer
    Dim totalMoney As Integer
    'open the database connection
    strSQL = "SELECT MAX(Total_Money) FROM Sales WHERE Concert_Id =" + Mid(cboVenue.Text, 1, 4)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    'read the record returned
    dr.Read()
    If IsDBNull(dr.Item(0)) Then
        totalMoney = txtPrice.Text
    Else
        DisplayMoneyTaken = dr.Item("Total_Money") + Val(txtPrice.Text)
    End If



    'close the database
    conn.Close()
    Return totalMoney

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that your query has a column named "Total_Money". You didn't name the single column your query returns.

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

When using an aggregate function, it is necessary to also assign an alias to that column. 
For example

```
strSQL = "SELECT MAX(Total_Money) as CaChing FROM Sales WHERE Concert_Id =" + Mid(cboVenue.Text, 1, 4)
```

If you do not assign an alias, the server will sometimes assign one. But you have to know or guess what it will be. Its a lot better to just pick one that makes sense.

You can also index items with a number, this is what you did when you were checking for NULLs. 
This same syntax could have been used when accessing the value.

```
 DisplayMoneyTaken = dr.Item(0) + Val(txtPrice.Text)
```